# libgdx ashley - How do I control a player the proper way (ECS framework)?

Tags: java, libgdx, 2d, entity-component-system

**What I have tried** *In the option 1, I created PlayerControlled classes to control a player (It's working properly). But I don't want the way I control a player like this, I have doubt it is not the proper way.*

```
// Option 1
class PlayerComponent implements Component {
     // player data here
}

class PlayerSystem extends IteratingSystem {
     // player logic here
}

class PlayerControlledComponent implements Component{
     // Player entity
}
class PlayerControlledSystem extends IteratingSystem {
     // Keyboard Input
     // Player entity
}

// Option 2
engine.getSystem(PlayerSystem.class).attack()

// Option 3
class PlayerController {

     PlayerConroller(Player player) {

     }

}
```

> Both option 1 & 2 are tested and working, option 3 is just an idea.

**Question**

- Which option is/are the proper way of controlling the player?
- Is there any other option to control the player using the ECS framework?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use a three layer approach: (pseudo code)

**Layer 1:**

Some class that handles the raw input coming from InputProcessor libgdx class like this:

```
public interface InputHandlerIF {
    void walk(int playerId, Vector2 direction);
    void jump();
    .....
}


class RawInputHandler implements InputProcessor {

    private InputHandlerIF listener;
    private Vector2 direction;
    onKeyDown(int keycode) {
        if(keycode == W) {
            direction = valueToWalkForward;
            listener.walk(playerId, direction);
        }
    }
}
```

So all raw input coming from libgdx framework is handled and translated to an actual game command like: walk, shoot, castSpell, etc. This layer allows you to filter input before it gets passed to the `InputHandlerIF`s: F.e. controller number in a local multi-player game.

**Layer 2:**

Then I have this a kind of command handler system which receives the commands:

```
public class InputHandlerSystem extends EntitySystem implements InputHandlerIF {
    public walk(int playerId, Vector2 direction) {
        positionComponents.getForPlayer(playerId).direction = direction;
    }
}
```

The systems knows all positionComponents of the player(s) and updates the values accordingly.

**Layer 3:**

PlayerMovementSystem which also knows the positionComponents and updates the players position (x and y) based on the time delta and `positionComponent.direction` value.

```
class PlayerMovementSystem extends IteratingSystem {
    update(float delta) {
        ... update player position
    }
}
```

Setup would look like this:

```
Engine engine = new Engine();
InputHandlerSystem ihs = new InputHandlerSystem();
RawInputHandler rih = RawInputHandler();
rih.registerListener(ihs);
engine.addSystem(ihs);
enigne.addSystem(new PlayerMovementSystem());
```